# Asp.Net unable to fire event on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio

I'm new to ASP.Net. I am trying to trigger action based on button click but the even is not getting triggered.

This is the button definintion in login.aspx:

```
<button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn_3" onclick="createAccount_Clicked" runat="server">
       Create Account
</button>
```

This is the intended button click event inside login.aspx.cs:

```
protected void createAccount_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Here's where you do stuff.
     string value = new_fullname.Value.ToString();
}
```

new_fullname is the Text I'm trying to read (defined in login.aspx):

```
<div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star" runat="server">
      <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="new_fullname" name="name" value=""
      placeholder="Full Name" runat="server">
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a GUI where you can double check everything is hooked up the way you want? That's normally the easiest way for me to make sure button/mouse clicks work the way I want.

Comment: Not sure what you said. Through ASP.Net I'm creating the GUI. Anyways, I solved it using the guidance of @Jamshaid Kamran

Comment: My mistake. Let me clarify what I meant. Are you able to preview the GUI? In Visual Studio there is a way to check that certain methods are connected properly through the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have set the button type to `submit` which actually submits the server form which does not guarantee the triggering of the intended event. What you should do is, set the button type to `button` to get it working.

This is how you will get it working:

```
<button type="button" value="submit" class="btn_3" onclick="createAccount_Clicked" runat="server">
       Create Account
</button>
```